# Trigger Twilio studio flow using Zapier Webhook

Tags: twilio, webhooks, zapier, twilio-studio

Truly grateful for any help here:

Trying to trigger a Twilio Studio flow from Zapier but with no luck so far.

---

Here is the Twilio guidance on how to trigger an execution: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/execution

Here, for example, is how the required data looks as CURL (those phone numbers are not real don't worry):

```
curl -X POST https://studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Executions \
--data-urlencode "To=+15558675310" \
--data-urlencode "From=+15017122661" \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

The required data is: `To` and `From` as well as the `TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID` and `TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN` authentication.

I would also like to pass through some data under `Parameters` as shown [in this bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EO4Y.png).

So the first step was the auth: Zapier was saying: "The app returned `Authentication Error - No credentials provided`".

Based on some other info, I have got past this (I think) by putting the Account SID and Auth token in the URL itself like this:

https://TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN@studio.twilio.com/v2/Flows/FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/Executions

(Maybe better/neater to put with the parameters, let me know)

But after the problem is now passing in the `To`, `From` and `Parameters`.

"The app returned `Missing required parameter To in the post body`".

[Here is how my Webhook Zap currently looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2eX9.png)

---

Thanks you for any help!

Comment: Got passed the issue just using the Form setting! I was overthinking it! Its very simple.

Comment: Just saw this comment now Q-/ Anyway there's an answer now.

Comment: Ah, no worries well it's helpful for anyone else who has this question, also will use the auth field like you have to keep things neat! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Form` as `Payload Type`:
[image]

For the basic authentication to work make sure to use a `|` to separate the username and password:
[image]